# C+X C+; not working

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

I work in emacs 27.1, Ubuntu 22, Terminal.

I need to comment out a block. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. However, the <kbd>;</kbd>  button is not accepted properly. It only makes an underlined e appear (only on screen, not the actual buffer).

[image]

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> gives the following information:

[image]

Opening nano and typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> I get an underline e:

[image]

I removed the [iBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) key binding using `ibus-setup` as explained in [Ctrl+Shift+e key conflict in Fedora](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29266/ctrlshifte-key-conflict-in-fedora/29408#29408)

After selecting lines and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, now I get a different message `Comment column set to 0`:

[image]

[image]

From the output of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> it appears that the third <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not picked up:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Please tell us what happens (ie., what message you see) when you type :`Ctrl` + `h` `k` `Ctrl` +`x` `Ctrl`+ `;`

Comment: Is this terminal Emacs or GUI Emacs?

Comment: That means Emacs isn't receiving the key `C-;`, it's getting `e̲` instead. I suspect your operating system is automatically translating `C-;`. Can you tell us what OS you are using, and if you are running emacs in a terminal, what terminal program?

Comment: If you open nano from terminal, what happens when you type `C-;`?

Comment: The culprit is likely ibus under Gnome which has emacs-hostile default bindings for starting an emoji (I think).

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29266/ctrlshifte-key-conflict-in-fedora/29408#29408

Comment: Try my first suggestion again. It looks like something else is interfering with your keypresses.

Comment: Step one is we need to get `C-h k C-x C-;` to confirm that Emacs is receiving `C-x C-;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

When a keypress/key combo doesn't do what you expect, the first thing to check is if the keys you pressed are actually the keys that Emacs received.

To do this, try:

- `C-h k`, to start searching help (`C-h`) for keys (`k`)
- `C-x C-;` to find the help for this particular key combo.

What we expect to see is:

> C-x C-; runs the command comment-line (found in global-map), which is
> an interactive native-compiled Lisp function in ‘newcomment.el’.

Things to check:

- are the keys listed (`C-x C-;`) the ones you pressed? If not, something at the operating system level, or in your terminal program if you're running Emacs in terminal mode, is translating the key presses into something else, and you'll have to fix that *outside* of Emacs
- is the listed command (`comment-line`) the command you expect? If not, there's a problem with your keybindings, or maybe you aren't in the major- or minor-mode you thought you were
- is the command not doing what you thought it would? In that case, check the help for the command, or the package, to see if you misunderstood it, or if there's a bug.

Comment: It seems that the second Ctrl is not picked up. See updated question.

Comment: I think this might be an issue with the terminal. `C-;` is not a recognized ASCII, which means the terminal only recognizes it as `;`. This isn't an issue with GUI Emacs. I'm not sure if this can be fixed in Terminal, or how.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161719/6096

Comment: From unix.stackexchange.com/q/161719/6096 if understand that using `C+;` is hopeless. Can I assign another keybinding to commenting out a block?

Comment: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs

Comment: skip to the "templates" section for examples, or read the whole page to learn all the options

Comment: I added `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-;") 'comment-line)` to `~/.emacs` which was successful in commenting out a region